# "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" error on first query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting into prepared statements using mysqli in PHP to help prevent SQL injection. I understand the situations where Commands out of sync would pop up, but this situation doesn't seem to be one of them. Here's a code snippet:

```
require_once("dbconnect.php")

$id = isset($_POST['g']) ? $_POST['g'] : false;

if ($id) {
    $id_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?");
    $id_stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
    $id_res = $id_stmt->execute();

    //FIX - per Jim's answer: Must store_result for the statement, so num_rows can be accurate.
    $id_stmt->store_result();

    if ($id_res && $id_stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        //user exists, do stuff
        $id_stmt->close();
        processUser($id);
    } else {
        $id_stmt->close();
        echo "Error, user ({$id}) doesn't exist.";
        echo " Problem: ".$mysqli->stat;
    }

}
```

Here is the basics of dbconnect:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db_name");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to make database connection!";
    die();
}

//This function is here so other files that connect to the DB can perform this common operation
function processUser($id) {
    $global $mysqli;

    $now = new DateTime();
    $now_str = $now->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $set_modified_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_modified=? WHERE id=?");
    $set_modified_stmt->bind_param("si", $now_str, $id);
    $set_modified_res = $set_modified_stmt->execute();
    $set_modified_stmt->close();

    return $set_modified_res;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
Error user (3) doesn't exist Problem: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

Note that the problem string is not in `$mysqli->error` but `$mysqli->stat` for some reason. Any ideas what that may be? Something's screwy here, and it's probably me and my code.

Edit, this is my `$mysqli` object right after the first `$id_stmt->execute()` call:

```
mysqli Object
(
    [affected_rows] => -1
    [client_info] => 5.5.33
    [client_version] => 50533
    [connect_errno] => 0
    [connect_error] => 
    [errno] => 0
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => Array
        (
        )

    [field_count] => 5
    [host_info] => Localhost via UNIX socket
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 0
    [server_info] => 5.5.33
    [server_version] => 50533
    [stat] => Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
    [sqlstate] => HY000
    [protocol_version] => 10
    [thread_id] => 9
    [warning_count] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$mysqli->stat` to (presumably) check for errors. It's likely this call the message is referring to.

Use `$mysqli->error` to show the last error instead.

See [mysqli->error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Also, please note the message on the [docs for num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php):

> Returns the number of rows in the result set. The use of mysqli_stmt_num_rows() depends on whether or not you used mysqli_stmt_store_result() to buffer the entire result set in the statement handle.

Try calling `store_result` before using num_rows:

```
$id_stmt->store_result();
```

Comment: $mysqli->error has an empty string, which is why I checked stat, I'll add a print_r for $mysqli to show the whole object

Comment: @Esaevian Hate to ask but does the user definitely exist? What do you get if you output the id and query and run that against the database yourself?

Comment: The user exists. I ran the code against the db itself "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=3" and I got the appropriate row.

Comment: Yes. I added the output of print_r for the $mysqli object right after the $id_stmt->execute() call.

Comment: @Esaevian I've added an edit. The culprit is likely your use of `num_rows`.

Comment: Aha! That was it! I'm slowly getting the hang of this :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to close first statement before preparing the next one. In your case you need to call `$id_stmt->close();` before `processUser();`

Comment: Well the flow of the program isn't getting to `processUser()` But that's a good point, I'll fix that up.